# Magento 2.2.7: Error cleaning cache by mode matchingTag

Tags: magento2, redis, magento2.2.7

When i am trying to add the robot.txt entry via admin, getting the following error

**Magento 2.2.7 Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Error cleaning cache by mode matchingTag: read error on connection.**

**Can anyone help me out on this.**

Comment: Any error into the log file of Magento?

Comment: can you please with your error log may be possible permission issue.

Comment: If you have solved this issue then please share your solution, i'm getting same error.